# Adding Facebook "Read" Buttons to an Article Page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am looking to do something I thought would be fairly straight forward, Adding a Read button below all articles on a News page that will post to an activity feed... Being new to the Facebook API I have found that finding current examples is not easy.

-The app has been created 
-functioning open graph objects
-I have a log in on the page

However, I continue to get this error 
"Message: (#100) The Action Type news:Read is not approved, so app 555555 can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app.  User 5555555 is not one of those roles."

Am approaching this the wrong way?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head prefix="og:h ttp://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# article: http://ogp.me/ns/article#">

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="5555555" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://name.page.com/default.aspx" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Second Article" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ogp.me/logo.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Second Article Description" />
    <meta property="article:author" content="http://name.page.com/">
    <meta property="article:section" content="Article" />
    <meta property="article:tag" content="Name" />

    <title>FACEBOOK</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<body>
    <div id="content" class="column">
        <div class="article">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Facebook Login" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));


        // Init the SDK upon load
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '5555555', // App ID
                channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/channel.html', // Path to your Channel File
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });

            // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {

                    // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
                    FB.api('/me', function (me) {
                        if (me.name) {
                            document.getElementById('auth-displayname').innerHTML = me.name;
                        }
                    })
                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
                } else {

                    // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
                }
            });

            // respond to clicks on the login and logout links
            document.getElementById('auth-loginlink').addEventListener('click', function () {
                FB.login();
            });
            document.getElementById('auth-logoutlink').addEventListener('click', function () {
                FB.logout();
            });
        }


        //Second Article
        function secondArticle() {

            //GET LOGIN STATUS
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                    // request, and the time the access token 
                    // and signed request each expire
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    alert(accessToken);


                    FB.api('me/news.reads' + '?article=http://facebook.Name.com/default.aspx&access_token=' + accessToken, 'post',

                    function (response) {
                        var msg = 'Error occured';
                        if (!response || response.error) {
                            if (response.error) {
                                msg += "\n\nType: " + response.error.type + "\n\nMessage: " + response.error.message;
                            }
                            alert(msg);
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                        }
                    });


                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                    // but has not authenticated your app
                    alert("Authorize")
                } else {
                    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.

                    alert("Login")
                }
            });
        }

    </script>



    <div id="contentContainer">
        <div id="login-container">           
            <h3>Login from site</h3>
            <div id="auth-status">
                <div id="auth-loggedout">
                    <a href="#" id="auth-loginlink">Login</a>
                </div>
                <div id="auth-loggedin" style="display: none">
                    Hi, <span id="auth-displayname"></span>(<a href="#" id="auth-logoutlink">logout</a>)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="column">
            <div class="article">
                <h3>Name Article V2</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut magna ligula, malesuada pellentesque mollis malesuada, varius in dolor. Aenean mollis nisl condimentum felis commodo at tincidunt purus interdum. Vivamus consectetur sodales quam, volutpat feugiat sapien lobortis pulvinar. Proin consectetur blandit libero tristique dictum. Fusce consectetur massa non magna convallis ac congue felis sagittis. Nulla nec turpis dui, vitae egestas quam. Proin lobortis dictum faucibus. Aenean eget elit nec quam imperdiet fermentum a vel magna. Ut viverra eros sit amet nibh varius lacinia. Duis porttitor augue condimentum arcu bibendum ut accumsan turpis lobortis. Nam vulputate, mauris non fermentum ornare, dui metus commodo odio, id tempor neque leo vel turpis. Donec ultricies imperdiet tincidunt.</p>
                <p>Nulla facilisi. Donec laoreet lacinia vulputate. Proin accumsan commodo est, id aliquam dolor gravida eget. Duis quam nisl, rutrum vel lobortis sit amet, condimentum id purus. Integer ut dignissim augue. Fusce bibendum tempus elit, in fermentum odio sagittis et. Sed luctus viverra urna ac porttitor. Duis erat nisi, porta eu cursus sed, posuere at est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel erat vel diam vehicula posuere eu eu leo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam mattis fringilla mi.</p>
                <p>Etiam id mi ipsum, non aliquam velit. Proin rutrum ante eget urna euismod accumsan. Nam id velit neque. Nunc aliquam, elit non porta aliquet, nisi orci malesuada tortor, quis interdum nisl mi a felis. Duis tristique, elit eu facilisis egestas, sem sapien porta orci, et imperdiet augue est ac velit. Nulla facilisi. Nam enim enim, sollicitudin at elementum vitae, varius vulputate magna. Nullam posuere lorem sit amet magna euismod sit amet ornare nisl tempus. </p>
                <input type="button" value="Read" onclick="secondArticle();" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to submit any Open Graph action you want to use in your app for *approval* (even if it’s the build-in ones).

In your app settings where you define your actions there are links that take you to the approval process.

For further details see also: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/

Comment: I am testing with a developer account and tester account.  The first time I clicked the link for the developer account it worked, but tester gave "Message: (#100) The Action Type news:Read is not approved, so app 555555 can only publish to administrators, developers, and testers of the app. User 5555555 is not one of those roles." Strange that it would react differently for each.